# Finite subgroups of unitary groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, matrices

Let $n$ be an integer. Camille Jordan showed that there exists some $m \in {\mathbb N}$ (depending on $n$), such that for any pair of $n \times n$-unitaries $u,v \in U(n)$ which generate a finite group, one has $[u^m,v^m] = 1_n$. (In fact, he showed that any finite subgroup of $GL(n)$ has a abelian normal subgroup of finite index, bounded independently of the subgroup.)

In particular, the set of pairs that generate a finite subgroup cannot be dense in $U(n) \times U(n)$ for $n \geq 2$. Indeed, a generic pair of unitaries in $U(2)$ generates a free group. I am asking whether a *stable* version could still be true.

> **Question**  Let $n$ be an integer, let $u,v$ be a pair of unitaries in $U(n)$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. Is there some integer $k \in {\mathbb N}$ and unitaries $u',v' \in U(nk)$, such that  $\|u \otimes 1_k-u'\| \leq \varepsilon$ and $\|v \otimes 1_k - v'\| \leq \varepsilon$ (with respect to the standard embedding $U(n) \subset U(nk)$, $u \mapsto u \otimes 1_k$), and
>   the unitaries $u',v'$ generate a finite group?

The question does only make sense once one has fixed a norm on $M_n {\mathbb C}$ for all $n \in {\mathbb N}$. I would either take the normalized Hilbert-Schmidt norm, i.e. $\|x\| = \frac1n Tr(x^*x)^{\frac12}$ for $x \in M_n \mathbb C$, or the operator norm.

(More globally seen, the questions are equivalent to the questions whether for the unitary group of certain UHF-algebras or the hyperfinite $II_1$-factor, pairs of unitaries generating a finite subgroup are dense in the natural topologies.)

Comment: I don't believe this can be true (i.e., I think the answer to the question has to be "no") but I don't see how to approach it.

Answer (score 8):

This might help: If $u$ and $v$ are both close enough to scalars in the operator norm,
and $\varepsilon$ is small enough, then no matter how large $k$ is, if the group generated by $u^{\prime}$ and $v^{\prime}$ is finite, then it still has to be Abelian. The reasoning is something like this:  I use the operator norm : given a unitary matrix $M$, there is a unique scalar $\lambda$ ( in the interior of the unit disk unless $M$ itself is a scalar matrix) with $\|M- \lambda I\|$ minimal, and this only depends on the spectrum of $M$. In particular, we can only have $\|M -\lambda I\| < \frac{1}{2}$ for a scalar $\lambda$ if the eigenvalues of $M$ all lie on an arc of length less than $\frac{\pi}{3}$ on the unit circle.It is essentially a Theorem of Frobenius that if $G$ is a finite group of unitary matrices, then the subgroup $H$ generated by the matrices at distance less than $\frac{1}{2}$ from a scalar is an Abelian normal subgroup. If $u$ and $v$ are close enough to scalars, and $\varepsilon$ is small enough then we can make both $\|u^{\prime} - \lambda I\|$
and $\| v^{\prime} - \mu I\|$ less than $\frac{1}{2}$ for suitable scalars $\lambda,\mu$. So if they 
generate a finite group, it must be Abelian. Note added: I will add a little more detail.
 One proof of Jordan's theorem uses a compactness argument and a kind of contraction Lemma.
Let $[a,b]$ denote $a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$. If $a$ and $b$ are unitary, then 
$$\| I-[a,b] \| = \|I - a^{-1}b^{-1}ab \| = \|ab-ba \|$$
$$ = \| (a-I)(b-I) - (b-I)(a-I)\|
\leq 2 \|a-I\| \|b-I\|$$. Hence if $\| I-a\| < \frac{1}{2}$, then $\|I- [a,b] \| < \|I-b\|$
for all $b.$ Hence in a finite group $G$ of unitary matrices, let $H$ be the subgroup generated
by those elements of $G$ with $\|I-h\|<  \frac{1}{2}$. For any $h \in H$ with 
$\|I - h \| < \frac{1}{2}$, we have $[g,h,h, \ldots ,h] = 1$ for all $g \in G$. By a theorem of Baer, $H$ is nilpotent. With a little more work, you actually get $H$ Abelian. (This is a kind of hybrid of arguments of Frobenius and a little more finite group theory. More or less the same line of reasoning led to a similar theorem by
Zassenhaus on discrete groups, and this led to the idea of a Zassenhaus neighbourhood in a
Lie group). Note that if $x,y$ are in different cosets of $H$ in $G$, we must have 
$\|x-y\| \geq \frac{1}{2}$, so the compactness of the unit ball of $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ gives
a fixed bound on $[G:H]$. But the same argument works when $\| a - \lambda I \| < \frac{1}{2}$
for some scalar $\lambda$, using $$\|ab - ba \| = \| (a-\lambda I)(b-\mu I) - (b-\mu I)(a-\lambda I)\|$$ for any scalars $\lambda,\mu$, and replacing $H$ by the group generated by elements at 
distance less than $\frac{1}{2}$ from any scalar. (Added in response to comment below): You do need a little argument to get from $H$ nilpotent to $H$ Abelian, but the statements above are all accurate. It is important to remember that $H$ is generated by elements within distance $\frac{1}{2}$ of a scalar. Any such element has all its eigenvalues on an arc of length less than $\frac{\pi}{3}$ on $S^{1}$. No subset of the "multiset" of eigenvalues of such an element has zero sum (it's clear eg, if you rotate so that all eigenvalues have positive real part). Let $\chi$ be the character of the given representation of $H$. Let $\mu$ be an irreducible constituent of $\chi$. By the remark above, if $\|h -\alpha I \| < \frac{1}{2}$ for some scalar $\alpha$, then $\mu(h) \neq 0.$ But if $\mu$ is not linear, it is induced from a character of a maximal subgroup $M$, which is normal as $H$ is nilpotent. But then $\mu$ vanishes on all elements of $H$ which are outside $M$. Hence the elements at distance less than $\frac{1}{2}$ from a scalar must all lie within $M$. But since $M$ is proper, and such elements generate $H$, this is a contradiction. Hence $\mu$ must be linear after all. Since $\mu$ was arbitrary, $H$ is Abelian.

Comment: I see that if $H$ is finite, then it is nilpotent. In fact it has an abelian subgroup of finite index, only depending on the dimension of the ambient $U(n)$. But $n$ is not fixed here. I do not see how you conclude that $H$ is abelian.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is a coincidence that only two weeks ago I could find myself an answer to the question above. You can find at least the statements in my answer below. My impression was that using only Frobenius-Baer-Jordan type arguments could not yield a negative answer to my question; but I might be wrong. I am really curious if this actually works.

Comment: Glad that you found your own solution. I have added some detail to my original answer, because it was too long for a comment, but what I said was accurate. 

Comment: Very nice! I did not know about the application of character theory to this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot accept your nice answer on MathOverflow, since - long ago - I was giving a bounty to a solution of the problem. After this bounty has passed, the system does not allow to accept answers formally.

Comment: I do not understand (or care really) anything about bounties. I just like to help find solutions to problems. 

Comment: I agree. Thanks for finding this nice solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In the meantime I could answer the question myself; at least if one considers the metric induced by the norm. This will be contained in a forthcoming joint preprint with Ken Dykema. We can show two theorems:

> **Theorem 1:** For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ and unitaries $a,t \in U(n)$ such that $\|a-1\|\geq 1$ and
>   $$\|1-tat^{-1}ata^{-1}t^{-1}a^{-2}\| < \varepsilon.$$

and

> **Theorem 2:** There exists $\varepsilon_0>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, and any two unitaries $a,t \in U(n)$ which generate a finite group: 
>   $$\|1-tat^{-1}ata^{-1}t^{-1}a^{-2}\| < \varepsilon \leq \varepsilon_0$$
>   implies
>   $$\|1-a\|< 1/4-\sqrt{1/16-\varepsilon}.$$

This together implies that the answer to my question above is negative. The details are not complicated but a bit too long for putting them in this answer. I will post a link to the preprint as soon as it is ready.

Comment: is this also true for Hilbert-Schmidt norm?

Comment: Theorem 1 holds. The group $G=\langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}ata^{-1}t^{-1}=a^2 \rangle$ is known to be sofic; so Theorem 2 fails.

Comment: I meant to ask the original question, it seems that H.-S. is natural framework for it.

Comment: I do not know about the answer to my question above for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm.

Comment: I think that since $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ is a finite dimensional Banach Space (of course, it's a Banach algebra, but some of the
natural norms on it (as linear space) aren't submultiplicative, so
aren't algebra norms), it doesn't really matter which norm you use when you are talking about density questions, since all norms 
on a finite-dimensional Banach Space are equivalent.

Comment: Geoff: the constants of equivalence depend on $n$, so that in trying to answer questions about "all $n$ simultaneously" your reasoning doesn't always work

Comment: Yemon: Yes, you are right. I was a bit casual in that statement.
I'll think more precisely about the H-S norm.