# Subgroups of U(M_n)

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, matrices

can any subgroup of the unitary group of full matrix alg $M_d(\mathbb{C})$ be approximated on finite
sets by a finite subgroup?

i.e. is the following True or false?
Let $n, d$ be positive integers and let
$u_1,..., u_n$ be in the unitary group $U_d=U (M_d(\mathbb{C}))$ of $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. Then for
every $\epsilon > 0$ there are $v_1, ..., v_n$ in $U_d$ such that
$\| u_k - v_k \| < \epsilon$ for $k = 1, .., n$ and such that the
subgroup of $U_d$ that $v_1, ..., v_n$ generate is finite.

Comment: can you write more details, what kind of approximation do you mean?

Comment: regard M_n(C) as B(C^n) the bounde operators on the f.d. Hilbert space C^n

Comment: Any such group is residually finite...  But it sounds more like you're asking whether any subgroup is a Gromov--Hausdorff limit of finite subgroups.  I doubt this is true - for instance, it's not true in SO(3), where the only infinite families of subgroups are cyclic and dihedral.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to: (a) format it correctly, with words spelled in full and sentences capitalized; and (b) fully explain every definition you are using.  By asking a question here, you are asking other people to do work for you.  Phrasing your question clearly and correctly shows that you respect this fact.

Comment: the following question is related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34625/finite-subgroups-of-unitary-groups

Comment: True or false: Let $n, d$ be positive integers and let
$u_1,..., u_n$ be in the unitary group $U_d=U (M_d(\mathbb{C}))$ of $M_d(\mathbb{C})$. Then for
every $\epsilon > 0$ there are $v_1, ..., v_n$ in $U_d$ such that
$\| u_k - v_k \| < \epsilon$ for $k = 1, .., n$ and such that the
subgroup of $U_d$ that $v_1, ..., v_n$ generate is finite.

"text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>

Comment: I hope my last comment clarifies the original problem! many thanks

Comment: As a purely linguistic comment, the question "Can any subgroup of ..." is ambiguous. It could mean either "Is this true for some subgroup?" or "Is this true for all subgroups?". The meaning of "any" is often unclear·

Answer (score 12, accepted):

no, it is not true. the following is contained in Andreas Thom [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34625/finite-subgroups-of-unitary-groups).

from the first paragraph of his question:

> Let $n$ be an integer. Camille Jordan
>   showed that there exists some $m \in
> > {\mathbb N}$ (depending on $n$), such
>   that for any pair of $n \times
> > n$-unitaries $u,v \in U(n)$ which
>   generate a finite group, one has
>   $[u^m,v^m] = 1_n$.

Take $u_1,u_2\in{U}(n)$ that generate a free group (easy to construct for $n\geq{2}$), and let $m$ be as above. Then, since $v_1^m,v_2^m$ commute, 
$$
\|u_1^mu_2^m-u_2^mu_1^m\|\leq{}2\|u_1^m-v_1^m\|+2\|u_2^m-v_2^m\|\leq{}4m\varepsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary we have a contradiction.